# NUXT 3 fetching data on the client side

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

For example we have the posta api which can return posts (get) and create new ones (post).

First i am need to get them on the server side.
I am do that on the **asyncData** option like that.
I am use **useFetch** composible to prevent double data fetching by **$fetch**.
https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/dollarfetch

Okey,i am have the post data getting by the server side.
But now i am want to be able to add some data using **methods options api**.

Should my function to be **async** prefixed or that is unnessery if i would use it only on the client side?
Which method should i use to post some data if **i want to use the funtion only on the client side**?

```
export default defineNuxtComponent({
   
    async asyncData () {
        return {
            posts: useFetch ('/api/posts')['data']
        }
    },

   methods:{
    post(event : Event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // post form data to api

       $fetch('/api/posts',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.form)
        })
        // this.posts.push(data);

    
    },
}
```

Is using

```
 the $fetch('/api/posts',{
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(this.form)
        })
```

is the right way?
How can i refresh posts on the client side after. Something like

```
axios.post().then(data)=>{this.posts.push(data)}
```

In official docs https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching
says :

> useFetch, useLazyFetch, useAsyncData and useLazyAsyncData only work
> during setup or Lifecycle Hooks

In the nuxt module site https://axios.nuxtjs.org/
says:

> Axios module supports Nuxt 2. Nuxt 3 users can use the new isomorphic
> $fetch API (migration guide).

So should i use or not the $fetch , useFetch, useLazyFetch, useAsyncData and useLazyAsyncData during client side fetches or no?

I cant find any example in the nuxt3 docs to using fetch in the methods like clicking on buttons etc.

Comment: You are using `defineNuxtComponent` to create your component, that is the options API way of doing it. `useFetch` is a composable and is meant to be used with `<script setup>`. So I can't predict the behaviour if you mix nuxt2 intended code with nuxt3 composables. [Check the docs on defineNuxtComponent](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/utils/define-nuxt-component#definenuxtcomponent)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of how your component might look like:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="form.searchTerm" />
    <input v-model.number="form.pageSize" type="number" />
    <button @click="getPosts">Get posts</button>
  </div>
  <template v-if="posts.length">
    <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
      <pre v-text="JSON.stringify(post, null, 2)" />
    </div>
  </template>
</template>
<script setup>
const posts = ref([])

const form = reactive({
  searchTerm: '',
  pageSize: 25
})

const getPosts = async () => {
  const { data } = await useFetch('/api/posts', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(form)
  })
  posts.value = data || []
}

// if you want fetch when component mounts:
onMounted(getPosts) 
</script>
```

The template is quite basic, but it should give you an idea on how it's using the data and how it all works.
Modify `form` to use whatever query params your backend expects.

---

Update: Although the above is the recommended way in Nuxt3, Options API is still available. This should do it:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    posts: []
  }),
  methods: {
    async getPosts() {
      const { data } = await $fetch('/api/posts', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.form)
      })
      this.posts = data
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So i am must to use composition api? Can i use   const { data } = await useFetch('/api/posts', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(form)
  }) inside method in options api?

Comment: `useFetch` is only available in `setup()`/`<script setup>`. It cannot be used outside of Composition API. And it's the recommended path forward. Options API is still usable so you don't have to transition everything at once. But you can't use composables inside Options API.

Comment: Oh,thx for your answer. I am do not want to use nuxt 2 in the new project still it will be out of support soon or later. That sad that i cant use options api fine in the nuxt 3 . Becouse even in the vue3 docs says that i can stay in options api and mix it with composition. But in real i understood that most community is using composition now and i must to do so if i want to use new nuxt.

Comment: @Sergei, actually, I'm going through the docs right now and what you want is possible. But, again, not recommended. I'll update my answer with how you can do it.

Comment: @SergeiIllarionov, I've added how you could use `$fetch` in Options API. I haven't tested it, but it should work, according to docs. If it doesn't, also try `this.$fetch` instead of `$fetch`. Let me know which one works, to update the answer, if necessary.

Comment: thx . I will try it later,but seems like is real better to switch on composition api .Becouse even that simple questionabout options api was opened 4 days before i get answer.And its realy hard to find some examples with options api

Comment: I've just tested it in a sandbox. `$fetch` is generally available in a nuxt app. `defineNuxtComponent()` wrapper in not needed for the above case, because it doesn't use `asyncData` function.

Comment: Ye,in your case thats only client. in real case it can be mixed with some ohter anyncs methods

Comment: Here is my hybrid approach keeping the non-composition api syntax of components .. yet some unrelated issue with multiple useFetch https://stackoverflow.com/q/78101911/986160