# Multiple uses of useFetch is causing [nuxt] A composable that requires access to the Nuxt instance was called outside of a plugin, Nuxt hook,etc

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-composition-api, nuxt3, usefetch

I am writing my Nuxt3 components in the non-composable way and I am not willing to refactor them. I am using `useFetch` instead of `$fetch` to avoid double requests in client and server side.. By using `.data.value` on the refs of `useFetch` it works without a problem for only one `useFetch`, until I introduce a second one:

This works:

```js
export default {
  async serverPrefetch() {
    const store = useDataStore()
    await this.fetchData(store);
  },
  mounted() {
    const store = useDataStore()
    this.fetchData(store);
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData(store) {
      const yesterdayBevData = await useFetch('/api/yesterdayBevs')
      store.setYesterdayBevs(yesterdayBevData.data.value)

      const bevData = await $fetch('/api/getBevSection/1')
      
      store.setBevModels(bevData)
    },
  }
}
```

but this doesn't work (I replaced one `useFetch` with `$fetch` and changed the de-ref code):

```js
export default {
  async serverPrefetch() {
    const store = useDataStore()
    await this.fetchData(store);
  },
  mounted() {
    const store = useDataStore()
    this.fetchData(store);
  },
  methods: {
    async fetchData(store) {
      const yesterdayBevData = await useFetch('/api/yesterdayBevs')
      store.setYesterdayBevs(yesterdayBevData.data.value)

      const bevData = await useFetch('/api/getBevSection/1')
      
      store.setBevModels(bevData.data.value)
    },
  }
}
```

It seems to be a limitation of composable:
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/25099

I tried converting the code to something like that:

```js
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
const bevData = await nuxtApp.runWithContext(() => useFetch('/api/getBevSection/'+key))
const yesterdayBevData = await nuxtApp.runWithContext(() => useFetch('/api/yesterdayBevs'))

store.setYesterdayBevs(yesterdayBevData.data.value)
store.setBevModels(bevData.data.value.bev)
```

Now I don't get the error but I see a request in the client where I shouldn't for the second request

What am I missing? Or is there no way to have multiple fetches and have them accessible in both server and client?